# list index out of range python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

List index out of range error occurs at the line

```
if large_l[lg_index] ==small_l[sl_index]:
```

Here the code works fine when the values of following are,

```
correctword = "syria"
incorrectword = "siria"
```

but when assigning value as follows,

```
correctword = "syria"
incorrectword = "syri"
```

the above mentioned error has occurred. If could, tell me a way to get rid from this error.
Thank you

```
correctword = "syria"
incorrectword = "syri"

l1 = list(correctword)
l2 = list(incorrectword)

if len(l1) < len(l2):
    large_l= l2
    small_l = l1
else:
    large_l =l1
    small_l = l2

missmatchstart = False
lg_mismatch_start_index = 0
sl_mismatch_start_index = 0
lg_index = 0
sl_index = 0
del_count=0
add_count = 0
sub_count = 0
for l1_item in large_l:
    for l2_item in small_l:
        if large_l[lg_index] ==small_l[sl_index]:
            if missmatchstart == False:
                sl_mismatch_start_index = sl_index
                lg_mismatch_start_index = lg_index
            print(large_l[lg_index])
            print("addition ")
            print(add_count)
            print("deletion ")
            print(del_count)
            print("substitution ")
            print(sub_count)
            if lg_index-lg_mismatch_start_index == sl_index-sl_mismatch_start_index:
                sub_count += sl_index-sl_mismatch_start_index
                lg_index+= 1
                sl_index+= 1
            elif lg_index-lg_mismatch_start_index > sl_index-sl_mismatch_start_index:
                sub_count += sl_index-sl_mismatch_start_index
                del_count += ((lg_index-lg_mismatch_start_index) - (sl_index-sl_mismatch_start_index))
                lg_index+= 1
                sl_index+= 1
            elif lg_index-lg_mismatch_start_index < sl_index-sl_mismatch_start_index:
                sub_count += lg_index-lg_mismatch_start_index
                add_count += ((sl_index-sl_mismatch_start_index) - (lg_index-lg_mismatch_start_index))
                lg_index+= 1
                sl_index+= 1
            missmatchstart = False
            break
        else:
            print(large_l[lg_index])
            if(missmatchstart == False):
                lg_mismatch_start_index = lg_index
                sl_mismatch_start_index = sl_index
                print("missmatch large")
                print(lg_mismatch_start_index)
                print("missmatch small")
                print(sl_mismatch_start_index)
                missmatchstart =True
                sl_index+=1
            else:
                sl_index+=1
            if sl_index== len(small_l)-1:
                lg_index +=1
                sl_index = sl_mismatch_start_index
                #del_count +=1
                break
            # elif lg_index == sl_index == len(small_l):
            #     sub_count +=

if lg_index >=len(large_l)-1:
    del_count += len(large_l)- lg_index
#elif missmatchstart ==True:

print(add_count)
print(del_count)
print(sub_count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to replace the condition on line 24:

```
if large_l[lg_index] ==small_l[sl_index]:
```

with:

```
if l1_item == l2_item:
```

There might be other bugs there, you should make your code more modular by splitting it into functions (in a reasonable matter) - it will be easier to maintain and debug!